# Having trouble aligning <aside> to the left of <article> using float

Tags: html, css

`tldr;` I am trying to put the aside-section to the left of the article-section (like a `sidebar/sidecolumn` however my "float" does not seem to work at all. How do I do this *without* editing the HTML-code? I only want to edit it in the CSS-file. I am a beginner so I appreciate the help!

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
section {background-color: cornsilk;overflow:auto;float: right;}
article {color: black;float: right;}
article footer {font-style: italic;font-size: 15px;color: black; background-color: cornsilk;text-align: left;}
#wrapper {width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;}

h1 {
background-color: #666;

text-align: center;
font-size: 35px;
color: white;
}
footer {
background-color: #666;

text-align: center;
font-size: 35px;
color: white;
font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, "sans-serif";
float: right;

}
aside { 
float: left;

}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header><h1>text</h1></header>
  <article>
    <section>
      <header><h2>Om CSS</h2></header>
      <p>text</p> 
      <p>text</p>
      <p class="linktext">Här är en <a href="https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets"> artikel om CSS</a> på Wikipedia</p>
      <footer>text</footer>     
    </section>
    <section>
      <header><h2>Om märkspråk</h2></header>
      <p>text</p> 
      <p>text</p>
      <p class="linktext">Här är en <a href="https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5"> artikel om HTML5</a> på Wikipedia</p>
      <footer>text</footer>     
    </section>
  </article>

  <aside> 
    <h1>Bildgalleri</h1>
    <img src="images/html5.png " alt="html5">
    <img src="images/css.png" alt="css3">
  </aside>
  <footer>&#169;</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: dont use flaot for styling purpose. USe css-grid or flexbox instead. With your code I would hardly recommend to start over and to programm clean for a specific intended layout. With your structure it will be hard to salavage the code even with css-grid and grid-area or flexbox with flex-order.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I will check the other options then (sadly I am only allowed to change the css, not the HTML-code or starting fresh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all your CSS to simplify it. Of course you can start to re-style everything.

The best overall solution in terms of compability will be the sue of flex-box. CSS-Grid would do the trick too but has limited support for IE11 & 13.

First at all, your main issue is the use of `float` which should not be sued for styling purpose. `float` is only intended to be used to float images within a paragraph (simliar to word or newspapers). Unfortunatly it still is repeatly tought as it was a hack befor HTML5 and the development of flexbox and css-grid in 2012. Since 2015 both flexbox and css-grid are a well established technique and there is no further reason to mis-use the float-hack.

Next issue is, your HTML structure. You have multiple `footer` and `header`elements and nested them within the structure. This requires the of the `>` selector to call only a specific footer or header element and not all of them.

The enxt structure issue is the ordering. Semantically you will display the elements either from `top to bottom` or from `left to right`. However your `<aside>` element is supposed to come befor the `<article>` element while it comes last within the structure. This requires the use of `order`(flex-order) within the CSS to change the order.

So what I did was to use `#wrapper { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap }` this applies flexbox to the container and tells the elements to wrap instead of nowrap (initial value). The intention is, that the ehaderr gets a width of 100% and the other elements should then be displayed below it instead of overflowing to the right.

Then you see, that the `<header>`, `<footer>`, `<aside>` and `<article>` elements got order property and value which allows me to reorder the structure within CSS as explained above.

If you need further explantion or information, feel free to ask.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#wrapper > header {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  order: 1;
}

#wrapper > aside {
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  order: 2;
}

#wrapper > article {
  width: 70%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  order: 3;
}

#wrapper > footer {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  order: 4;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>text</h1>
  </header>
  <article>
    <section>
      <header>
        <h2>Om CSS</h2>
      </header>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p class="linktext">Här är en <a href="https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets"> artikel om CSS</a> på Wikipedia</p>
      <footer>text</footer>
    </section>
    <section>
      <header>
        <h2>Om märkspråk</h2>
      </header>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p class="linktext">Här är en <a href="https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5"> artikel om HTML5</a> på Wikipedia</p>
      <footer>text</footer>
    </section>
  </article>

  <aside>
    <h1>Bildgalleri</h1>
    <img src="images/html5.png " alt="html5">
    <img src="images/css.png" alt="css3">
  </aside>
  <footer>&#169;</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, exactly this! Thank you. I haven't seen this use "#wrapper > article" for example before. And I need also to check what "order" does

Comment: perfect, I added an explanation which should cover the `>` selector aswell as the `order` property.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution where your HTML is completely unchanged (which I actually would not recommend at all, since the order of elements in there isn't ideal, and neither is the HTML structure in general).

The main thing is that I used `display: flex`  with `flex-direction: row-reverse` on the `#wrapper` and applied `position: absolute` to the header and footer, plus some paddings and margins on other elements to create space for that header and footer. I also deleted *all* floats. Other details/settings see below.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  position: relative;
}
section {
  background-color: cornsilk;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

article {
  color: black;
  padding: 60px 0;
}

article footer {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  background-color: cornsilk;
  text-align: left;
}

header h1 {
  background-color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
  margin: 0;
}
aside h1 {
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
#wrapper > header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
section:first-of-type > header {
   margin-top: 40px;
}
footer {
  background-color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>text</h1>
  </header>
  <article>
    <section>
      <header>
        <h2>Om CSS</h2>
      </header>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p class="linktext">Här är en <a href="https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets"> artikel om CSS</a> på Wikipedia</p>
      <footer>text</footer>
    </section>
    <section>
      <header>
        <h2>Om märkspråk</h2>
      </header>
      <p>text</p>
      <p>text</p>
      <p class="linktext">Här är en <a href="https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5"> artikel om HTML5</a> på Wikipedia</p>
      <footer>text</footer>
    </section>
  </article>

  <aside>
    <h1>Bildgalleri</h1>
    <img src="images/html5.png " alt="html5">
    <img src="images/css.png" alt="css3">
  </aside>
  <footer>&#169;</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: I just wondering if there is a specific reason to sue position absolute instead of flex-order like my solution. Is there any downsite to my solution that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @tacoshy No there isn't. It's just different

Comment: Thank you, this one works great too! I will study the edits you included as they are new to me

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do like this

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  background-color: cornsilk;
  overflow: auto;
  float: right;
}

article {
  color: black;
  float: right;
}

article footer {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
  background-color: cornsilk;
  text-align: left;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
}

footer {
  background-color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, "sans-serif";
  float: right;
}

aside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
}
```